# Importing SQL database Invalid default value for datetime

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am moving a database from one MySQL server to another, however when importing one table I end up with the error:

> 1067 - Invalid default value for 'date'

the table SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `log` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `url` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=165 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Importing to MySQL version 5.5.47   from 5.6.21

Comment: What version of MySQL are you importing to?

Comment: Show us about 10 lines of the import file.  You also might want to add unique key on id like (CREATE TABLE `log` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `url` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;).  Otherwise, inserting blank and null values worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL 5.5 you can only use `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` when the column datatype is `TIMESTAMP`, not `DATETIME`.

The [MySQL 5.5 documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/data-type-defaults.html) says:

> The exception is that you can specify `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as the default for a `TIMESTAMP` column.

In 5.6 they extended this to `DATETIME`, its [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-type-defaults.html) says:

> The exception is that you can specify `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as the default for `TIMESTAMP` and `DATETIME` columns.

So either change the datatype or remove the default value.

You should always be wary of migrating to an older version of any software, since it's often possible that your code is using new features that didn't exist previously. Updated versions usually provide backward compatibility (at least for a few releases), but there's no way for old versions to deal with unimplemented features from new versions.

Answer (score -1):

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is only acceptable on `TIMESTAMP` fields. `DATETIME` fields must be left either with a null default value, or no default value at all.

Comment: Did you read the page you linked to? It says **you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns**

Comment: @Barmar that was for MySQL 5.7, still the answer is correct.